# how to collect maximum and minimum values from a grep search pattern?

Tags: bash

I have a huge log.txt file from which I need to calculate the maximum and minimum throughput values.
so, as the first step I started to collect lines as below into a separate file with the below grep command:

```
grep "x=0 y=0 Time=" log.txt > new_log.txt
```

So, now I have a new_log.txt file that contains only lines as below patterns.
From this file, I need to calculate(in bash) the maximum and minimum Throughput values:-

```
0-00:42:35.598 <tracing>:[DEFAULT]:[PRINT]:0-00:42:35.598 (7420:428:512:32 =      74.205024) <0xfa91>:Mbps: x=0 y=0 Time=200 ms Throughput=98.5463 Mbit/s
0-00:42:35.598 <tracing>:[DEFAULT]:[PRINT]:0-00:42:35.598 (7420:428:512:32 =      74.205024) <0xfa91>:Mbps: x=0 y=0 Time=200 ms Throughput=12.2456 Mbit/s
0-00:42:35.598 <tracing>:[DEFAULT]:[PRINT]:0-00:42:35.598 (7420:428:512:32 =      74.205024) <0xfa91>:Mbps: x=0 y=0 Time=200 ms Throughput=42.5675 Mbit/s
0-00:42:35.598 <tracing>:[DEFAULT]:[PRINT]:0-00:42:35.598 (7420:428:512:32 =      74.205024) <0xfa91>:Mbps: x=0 y=0 Time=200 ms Throughput=35.7289 Mbit/s
0-00:42:35.598 <tracing>:[DEFAULT]:[PRINT]:0-00:42:35.598 (7420:428:512:32 =      74.205024) <0xfa91>:Mbps: x=0 y=0 Time=200 ms Throughput=79.5687 Mbit/s
```

Desired output:-

```
maximum Throughput=98.5463 Mbit/s
minimum Throughput=12.2456 Mbit/s
```

Any support is appreciated.

Comment: I suggest to take a look at `awk`.

Comment: `grep -Po 'x=0 y=0 Time=.*Throughput=\K.*' log.txt | sort -hr | sed -n '1p;$p'`

Comment: @SasankSaiSujanAdapa : While the comment given by NahuelFouilleuil (I think it should go into an answer instead of a mere comment) is perfect for your concrete problem, bear in mind (if you want to do more number manipulations) that bash does not support fractional numbers. Consider switching to (for instance) zsh or Ruby for this kind of task.

Comment: @user1934428 Yes i agree it should be in the answer section.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` for that purpose.
E.g.:

```
cat new_log.txt | awk '
BEGIN { 
  mi=999999.9; 
  ma=0.0; 
}
{
  v=substr($12,12); 
  if (v<mi) mi=v; 
  if (v>ma) ma=v;
} 
END { 
  printf("maximum Throughput=%f Mbit/s\n",ma); 
  printf("minimum Throughput=%f Mbit/s\n",mi);
}'
```

You even can use it on the output of the `grep`, you do not need to store the file.

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work. @quantummind
maximum Throughput=0.000000 Mbit/s
minimum Throughput=0.000000 Mbit/s

I think there was a mistake in format. Due to that subString number is not correct. Not sure.

0-00:42:35.598 <tracing>:[DEFAULT]:[PRINT]:0-00:42:35.598 (7420:428:512:32 =      74.205024) <0xfa91>:Mbps: x=0 y=0 Time=200 ms Throughput=79.5687 Mbit/s